# Equatable package use for nullable value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, iequatable

[image]
I am using an extension for creating flutter class and I want to use equatable with it but it seem like it doesn't support nullable, is there a way to use it or do I have to use the generate equatable that the extension provide.

Comment: Avoid positing code-image, include code-snippet, find more about [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`props`](https://pub.dev/documentation/equatable/latest/equatable/Equatable/props.html) accept nullable data, change like

```dart
  List<Object?> get props => [];
```

Comment: A comment above did something similar does it work if I don't have the value ?

Comment: As the question seek if the props accept nullable data or not, so the answer is yes it accept nullable data. You've need to put your prop inside `[]` and you already know it. Check the link for the source code to prove that it actually accept null data.

Answer (score 1):

you problem is in `List<Object>` which is not using `?`, try this:

```
@override
  List<Object?> get props => [name, surename];
```

Comment: But does it affect the equatable package, because I don't think they allow nullable

Comment: the package said that if you are using variable which might be null, you this approach.